# How to add dynamic Values in Listview with inner ArrayItems?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin and I have one listview which contains two label and one string array. How can I bind this items in listview?
Items may be 1 to 5 based on data.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `ContentView` to act as a container for the `StackLayout`. Then you can bind the `string[]` property to the `ContentView`'s `Content` property. And finally, you can use a value converter to convert the `string[]` value into a horizontal `StackLayout`.

For example:

```
<ContentPage 
    ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.MyValueConverters">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:ArrayToStackLayoutConverter x:Key="arrayToStackLayout" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    ... 
    ... place the ContentView wherever you want the labels to appear ...

    <ContentView
        Margin="0"
        Padding="0"
        Content="{Binding MyStringArray,
                          Converter={StaticResource arrayToStackLayout}}" />

    ...

</ContentPage>
```

Just place the `<ContentView />` inside of your `ListView`'s `DataTemplate`, wherever you want the array of items to appear.

And then for the value converter:

```
namespace MyProject.MyValueConverters
{
    public class ArrayToStackLayoutConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var strArray = (string[])value;

            var layout = new StackLayout()
            {
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
            };

            foreach (var item in strArray)
            {
                var label = new Label()
                {
                    Text = item
                };

                var frame = new Frame()
                {
                    Content = label,
                    HasShadow = false,
                    Padding = 4,
                    OutlineColor = Color.Black,
                    CornerRadius = 2
                };

                layout.Children.Add(frame);
            }

            return layout;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works fine. Can you please tell me how can I display border around label as in image?

Comment: @SrustiThakkar I updated the answer, to show the label being wrapped in a frame with a border (because labels don't have a `Border` property). It might have a negative impact on performance though, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Somehow border is not displaying.

Comment: If its on Android, it looks like it might be a bug https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=27460 It looks like there are a few workarounds there

Comment: Ok. then how can we display border for android?

Comment: A simple workaround would to set `label.BackgroundColor = Color.White;`, `frame.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;` and `frame.Padding = 1;`. This will "simulate" a border around the label, although to be honest this isn't a good solution. I would recommend using a custom renderer

Comment: Ok Thank you, I will do it later with custom render.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyItem {
   public string Label1 {get; set;}
   public string Label2 {get; set;}
   public string[] Subitems {get; set;}
}

//viewmodel is something like List<MyItem>
List<MyItem> viewModel = GetDataFromService(...);

//xaml
<ListView BindingContext="viewModel">  //i can't remember exactly, maybe use <ListView.ItemSource>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="{Binding Label1}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Label2}" />
            <ListView BindingContext="Subitems">
               <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                    <BoxView ...> //set height, weight, border
                      <Label
                    </BoxView>
                 </DataTemplate>
           </ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

all in all, use an inner ListView inside the outer ListView.